# Echo Image instead of URL in PHP

Tags: php, image, api, instagram

I am trying to echo an image in PHP however I am only achieving the URL. This is using the Instagram API.

```
echo $pics['data'][0]['images']['standard_resolution']['url'];
```

Whats confusing me is where to use the `<img src= />` without the code breaking.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
echo "<img src=\"".$pics['data'][0]['images']['standard_resolution']['url']."\">";
```

Comment: It's funny how this line of code is an answer to some question.

Answer (score 5):

You will want to use the complex syntax for outputting values from complex variable types into double quoted and parsed strings.

Example:

```
echo "<img src='{$pics['data'][0]['images']['standard_resolution']['url']}'>";
```

Output:

```
<img src='http://nicenicejpg.com/350/150'>
```

[php codepad of example](http://codepad.viper-7.com/yw4fWD)

[From the PHP documentation on Strings, and more specifically Double Quoted strings.](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex)

> Any scalar variable, array element or object property with a string
>   representation can be included via this syntax. Simply write the
>   expression the same way as it would appear outside the string, and
>   then wrap it in { and }.

I believe this method of including strings adds to readability when there would otherwise be no advantage to assigning the value to a simple variable prior to it's use in a string.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that `$pics['data'][0]['images']['standard_resolution']['url'];` refers to an image url, you'll want to do something like...

```
<? $url = $pics['data'][0]['images']['standard_resolution']['url'];
...
echo "<img src=\"".$url."\">";
?>
```

This does the SAME thing that Duniyadnd suggested, but makes the output "part" a bit more readable.

Comment: Thanks, I'm sure both answers are correct - It may be something on my part why they aren't showing up. I will continue to plug, play and fix. Its appreciated